# How to read the docstring of test functions from a fixture?

Tags: python, pytest, docstring, conftest

I was trying to get the docstrings of all the test functions from a fixture defined in conftest.py, as shown in the code below, so that they can be analyzed for purposes.

But, from here how can I access the `__doc__` attribute of that function when the function is only available as a string (`request.node.name`) !?

Is there a way to read docstrings through `request` OR from other default pytest fixtures !?

Contents of conftest.py

```
  1 import pytest
  2 
  3 @pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
  4 def publish_to_pubsub(request):
  5     print("\n\nSTARTED Test '{}'".format(request.node.name))
  6     test_name = request.node.name
        // Here -  need to get the docstring of this function . 
  7     
  9     def fin():
 12         print("COMPLETED Test '{}'\n".format(request.node.name))
 13 
 14     request.addfinalizer(fin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Reference: [docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#request](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.FixtureRequest.function)

```
print(request.function.__doc__)
```